# WiFi getScanResults returns an empty list if GPS is off. (Android 6.0.1)

Tags: android, android-wifi

i tried to explain the problem in this gif

[image]

basically, this test app receives an "RSSI_CHANGED" intent and displays the scan results on the screen.

scan results are always empty unless GPS is enabled.

I guess my question is **why?**

---

> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions

I have "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" granted

Comment: Look at this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185370

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Rayes thanks! I'm stucked too in this problem "as design".

Answer (score 0):

You must declare `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. A location permission is required because `Bluetooth` scans can be used to gather information about the location of the user.

This information may come from the user's own devices

So you must give that `permission` and on the `GPS` for `Bluetooth` devices.

Answer (score 0):

Google, Apple, Microsoft, et al, build, maintain, and sell databases of Wi-Fi routers and their locations.  By requiring you to enable location functionality when scanning nearby WiFi networks, they acquire and update these data.