# List Wifi without enabling location service

Tags: android, android-wifi

While developing an app where I scan the WiFi, I found that it does not work if I turn off the location service on my phone. I have provided the app with all the necessary permissions. - ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

This is my code:

```
WifiManager manager= (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
manager.startScan();
```

In the receiver:

```
int found = manager.getScanResults().size();
```

This question answers part of the problem.
[Wifi scan results broadcast receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050101/wifi-scan-results-broadcast-receiver-not-working)

My questions are:

1. Is there a way for the app to list the Wifi access points if the location service is turned off?
2. If location service is absolutely necessary, is there a way for the app to turn on the location service while the app scans the wifi access points?

Comment: Google thinks that using Bluetooth or Wifi you can get the user's location while he doesn't want you to do that. That's why starting from Android 6 you have to request location permission to scan/connect to WIFI to clearly state that you are probably able to get the user's location using that services. Also AFAIK you don't have to turn on location services to scan WIFI, if you request location permissions.

Comment: @VladMatvienko When I turned off the location service, the count of Wifi access point was 0, when I turned it on, the count was the actual number of Wifi points. I am using Android 6.0

Comment: Have you requested the location permissions before getting WIFI networks?

Comment: Yes. I have. Seems to be an Android bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361064/wifi-getscanresults-returns-an-empty-list-if-gps-is-off-android-6-0-1?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure that you have requested it in runtime, not only declared it in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I have. Without requesting it in runtime, it would not work (with or without the Location Service).

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get the scanResult without GPS turned on is to set the app's `targetSDKversion` to `21 or lower`.

This will work even on **Lolipop** and above.

Answer (score 1):

**Android 8.0 and Android 8.1:**

A successful call to `WifiManager.getScanResults()` requires any one of the following permissions:

- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
- `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
- `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`

If the calling app does not have any of these permissions, the call fails with a SecurityException.

**Android 9 and later:**

A successful call to `WifiManager.startScan()` requires all of the following conditions to be met:

- Your app has the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission.
- Your app has the `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` permission.
- **Location services are enabled on the device** (under Settings > Location).

To successfully call `WifiManager.getScanResults()` ensure all of the following conditions are met:

- Your app has the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission.
- Your app has the `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission.
- **Location services are enabled on the device** (under Settings > Location).

If the calling app doesn't meet all of these requirements, the call fails with a SecurityException.

---

This is from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan Google Documentation.
Probably they needed the "Location services are enabled on the device" requirement for Android 6.+ because it is the version this permission restrictions first revealed, but they don't seem to had this requirement in documentations since no one has answered this question until now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for the app to list the Wifi access points if the
>   location service is turned off?

Yes, only system apps can get scan results without the location with the following permission:

> android.permission.PEERS_MAC_ADDRESS
>   permission